# How do I print something in Python n times?

Tags: python, printing

So i have a code

```
name = input("Enter your name: ")
age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
num1 = 100
sum = num1 - age
print((name + " in", sum, " years you'll have a hunderd years") * 3)
```

But when I execute it, it returns like this:

```
Enter your name: natasa
Enter your age: 34
('natasa in', 66, "years you'll have a hunderd years", 'natasa in', 66, "years you'll have a hunderd 
years", 'natasa in', 66, "years you'll have a hunderd years")
```

I would like it not to have these quotation marks in it and commas and parentheses. What can I do?

Comment: "But when I execute it, it returns like this:" It most certainly does not. The code has a syntax error. Please [edit] your question to include the actual code you are asking about.

Comment: You're right I forgot the commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code..

```
name = input("Enter your name: ")
age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
num1 = 100
summation = num1 - age
for i in range(3):
    print(name + " in " + str(summation) + " years you'll have a hunderd years")
```

Your Output will be..

```
Enter your name: Natasha

Enter your age: 25
Natasha in 75 years you'll have a hunderd years
Natasha in 75 years you'll have a hunderd years
Natasha in 75 years you'll have a hunderd years
```

You can make modifications as per your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use f-strings.

```
print(f"{name} in {sum} years you'll have a hunderd years"*3)
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove commas you should do something called formatting strings:

```
name + " in" + sum + " years...text.."
```

or better:

```
"{} in {} years...text..".format(name, sum)
```

Now you print one long string, that has three similar substrings. You should consider learning about loops, that will help you print one string three times:

```
for i in range(3):
    print('stuff')
```